# A rectangle has a perimeter of 8s x 1/4 units. Which of the following could not be the dimensions of the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

> A rectangle has a perimeter of $8s \times \frac{1}{4}$ units. Which of
>   the following could not be the dimensions of the rectangle?
>
> A. $3s$ units long and $s \times 1/8$ units wide
>
> B. $2s$ units long and $2s \times 1/8$ units wide
>
> C. $3s \times 1/16$ units long and $s \times 1/8$ units wide
>
> D. $2s \times 1/16$ units long and $2s \times 1/16$ units wide

What I did was, I combined $8s \times \frac{1}{4}$ to equal $2s$

Now I know the formula for the perimeter is:

$2L+2W=8s \times \frac{1}{4}$

Now only one of the answer is wrong but I plugged in A and B, and they both wrong. Does anyone see a mistake in this problem or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L+W=s$. So I think none of $A,B,C$ and $D$ gives $s$. Are you sure this question has only one correct answer? Or is it a multiple answer question?

Comment: The book is known for making mistakes so I believe this is just another one of them. I'll circle all the choices haha.